# Ajax error request returns "false" instead of text

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

In FireBug I see

```
 "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
 http://hostname:5987/controllerName/PageName?input=asdf%20%3Cd%20"
```

code

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success message " + data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('An Error occured.  Invalid characters include '<'');
                }
            });
```

On failure, I expect to see my Error message, but instead the message says "false".  How can I fix this to show my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply have a typo in your error function, you end up comparing two strings using `<` which in this case returns `false`;

```
alert('An Error occured.  Invalid characters include '<'');
```

should probably be;

```
alert('An Error occured.  Invalid characters include \'<\'');
```